# UIView is not showing up in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am currently dynamically adding a UIImage to my UIScrollView object and everything is working as intended. I need to add extra functionality now (a UIActivityIndicator in the center of the image when it is loading from the internet, and a label underneath) so I thought why not create a custom View which has all of these laid out as I need them to be, and then just load it into the scrollView. I have encountered a problem though, when I add it to the scrollView, nothing shows up. Here is what I have:

NewsViewController.m:

```
imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*numberOfPages, 303);
pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
dispatch_queue_t imageDownload = dispatch_queue_create("imageDownload", NULL);
__block NSData *temp;
    CustomImageView *customImageView = [[CustomImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 303)];
    [imageScrollView addSubview:customImageView];
    [[customImageView activityIndicator] startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(imageDownload, ^{
        temp = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wlfarm.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/farm.jpg"]]retain];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            customImageView.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:temp];
            [[customImageView activityIndicator] stopAnimating];
            [customImageView setNeedsDisplay];
            customImageView.caption.text = @"HAHAHAHAHHAHA";
            [imageScrollView setNeedsDisplay];
            [temp release];
        });
    });

    dispatch_release(imageDownload);
```

CustomImageView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomImageView : UIView
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *caption;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *caption;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@end
```

CustomImageView.m

```
#import "CustomImageView.h"  
@interface CustomImageView ()

@end

@implementation CustomImageView

@synthesize caption, imageView, activityIndicator;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

 - (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

I am including a screenshot of my XIB file, and the program running on the simulator. The first picture shows nothing in the scrollView(the attempt made by using my custom class), and the second page of the scroll view is the attempt made by adding a UIImageView to the UIScrollView(which worked). Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Am I not allowed to load a custom view into a UIScrollView? Thanks for your help!

IB Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz9UL.png

iOS Simulator No Image with CustomView Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhswq.png

iOS Simulator Image with UIImageView Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/97vmU.png

Comment: do you reference properly this custom view in the identity inspector?

Comment: Yeah, in my screenshot it shows the Custom class is CustomImageView which it should be. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: yes - sorry i didn't check your screenshot

Comment: Please share some relevant code of your CustomImageView class. It may well be that your custom image view is located properly and visible in principle but its subviews and prperties activityIndicator, caption and imageView ain't.

Comment: There isn't any code in the .m file of the CustomImageView class other than me synthesizing the properties. I included the view hierarchy in my screenshot of IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though `CustomImageView` is a subclass on `UIViewController`, not `UIImageView` or `UIView`. You ***can't*** add a `UIViewController` as a subview like that. change it to subclass `UIView` and it should work.

To load a `UIView` from a .nib, you need to declare your `IBOutlet` properties as you would for a `UIViewController`. Define the correct custom class in IB and connect everything up, including the base view. Then override the following method inside your custom view class.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
    //
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"<NIB NAME HERE>" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
  return self;
}
```

It seems you have cut and pasted methods from a `UIViewController` subclass into you `UIView` subclass. Start by deleting all the methods you've pasted in between  `@synthesize` and `@end` . A `UIView` subclass requires different methods to to load from a .nib, so you need to override the method shown above instead and use the line of code

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"<NIB NAME HERE>" owner:self options:nil];`

to load the nib.

Further to your comment about connecting the base view, here is what I mean:

After creating your custom class and nib file, open the nib and highlight "Files Owner" on the left, then on the top right hand side, select the icon 3rd from the left, looks like an ID card or something. In the "Class" box, add the name of your custom class.

In your customClass, add an `IBOutlet UIView` property called baseView, and add a UIView that covers the view in IB at the root level, connect these two. Then add everything else on top of that

you code would now look something like this:

CustomImageView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomImageView : UIView
{
    IBOutlet UIView *baseView
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *caption;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *baseView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *caption;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@end
```

CustomImageView.m

```
#import "CustomImageView.h"  
@interface CustomImageView ()

@end

@implementation CustomImageView

@synthesize baseView, caption, imageView, activityIndicator;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
    //
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"<NIB NAME HERE>" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.baseView];
    }
  return self;
}

@end
```

Provided you connect it all up in IB it should work fine, just remember to add the baseView

Comment: I think a `UIView` is probably your best bet. Can we see the CustomImageView.h to sure?

Comment: CustomImageView.h is given above. I subclassed UIView.

Comment: So I need to override initWithFrame and load the nib file in there? What do you mean by including my base view. Sorry, I am new to this, can you be a little more specific? Also, I want to add this view to a UIScrollView, would I still do this? [self addSubview:self.view];

Comment: Ah OK, I think the problem is that you have copied UIViewController subclass methods into a UIView subclass. UIView does not have the method `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` I'll edit my answer to expand and answer your questions

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it working. Can you explain to me why though I needed to load the Nib? I didn't set it equal to anything..why did that make a difference? Also, why did we add the self.view to self?

Comment: you didnt need to set it equal to anything because you define the owner as `self` when you load the nib. You need to add self.view to selfas the .nib is inflated (and self.view is connected to the nib) but not automatically added. TBH it is quite confusing, and if your new to iOS dev you will probably come across alot of things like this that don't seem to make sense, it's just quite different to other languages. But once you get your head round it all it becomes very easy to write stuff quickly

Comment: It isn't really intended to be like that, I think.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier `initWithNibName` belongs to controllers.
As I think, you're going the wrong way.

you have a ViewController and want to add a customView, to load dynamically a image from URLData.

*You have 2 Options:*
**Option 1:**  Do everything in IB:
In Interfacebuilder edit/(or add a new one) the ViewController's XIB File and add the views that you like. The file's owner is a UIViewController Class/Subclass. Do everything like you did before, except doing it in the view controller. In your App delegate initWithNibName your ViewController like so

```
    self.viewController = [[testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"testViewController" bundle:nil];
```

If you want to, initialize your own view controller, which you like to push and push it in the stack.

What you're doing wrong: You are initializing a customImageView with a Frame, but the nib doesn't get loaded automatically. The Properties are there, but the nib isn't.

If you really want a stable thing choose
**Option 2: Do everything programatically** (It is easier, more understanding and lightweight):
From your implementation we do the following:

**NewsViewController.m**

Do like you did before!!!

**CustomImageView.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomImageView : UIView
{
    UIImageView *imageView;
    UILabel *caption;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *caption;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@end
```

**CustomImageView.m:**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        caption = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 320, 50)];
        [caption setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 250)];
        [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(320/2-25, 460/2-25, 50, 50);
        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];


        [self addSubview:self.caption];
        [self addSubview:self.imageView];
        [self addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then do everything you did before. 
That would do a better job