# How to access member of a subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom View

```
@interface Slip : UIView{

  UIButton *number1;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIButton *number1;
@end
```

with a nib file, the "Slip" is the file´s owner of the nib File.

I initialize the View in a ViewController like this:

```
self.slip1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"SlipNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.slip1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 307.0f, 322.0f)];
[self.slips addSubview:self.slip1];
```

now I want to access the member of the Slip

```
[self.slip1.number1 setSelected:YES];
```

this line throws an exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x755e9d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key number1.'
```

How can I access the member (number1). I have 12 of these views in my ViewController and need to access them seperately. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't connected the `IBOutlet` to the button in Interface Builder. You should right click and drag from 'Files Owner' to the button and then select button1.

It's a problem associated with the `IBOutlet` not being linked properly to the button as nibs use KVC under the hood. You may also need to connect the root view of the nib to an `IBOutlet` in your `UIView` subclass.

Check out my other post here if you need more info on how to load `UIView` subclasses from nibs

[UIView is not showing up in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627152/uiview-is-not-showing-up-in-uiscrollview/11628158#11628158)

Comment: it seems like the Exception is thrown up WHEN I connect the Button with the IBOutlet. Anyone has an Idea why?

Comment: The connection is not done at run time, it is done in the .nib file before you compile you project. The crash is happening when you are trying to access the unconnected button, have you connected the IBOutlet to the button in the nib, as described above? A good way to tell is to look in your `Slip.h` file to the left of where your IBOutlet property is declared. There will be small thin grey circle, and if it is correctly connected, the circle will be filled. If this is not the case, then you have not connected the button correctly

Comment: I should have tell you, I removed the line already, it crashes on the self.slip1 =...line now. I have no clue why, it´s like some leprechaun is changing my code when I get a coffee. Thing is, as soon as I connect an IBOutlet with the Button I get the exception, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with how you are loading the UIView subclass from the nib. I would go back to basics, scrap the current way and read my answer to the other question. It's not that straightforward to achieve, but hopefully that should help

Comment: yes, should have read your post earlier, I just thought: tl;dr :) thank you!